# Restricted all routes expect the alowed one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Yeah, this might sound odd but we have a third party library which enable a sort of service consumed by a JavaScript application.  This third party library take care of calling the correct controller and action.

This works all very well but we now need to restrict the routes to this "ServiceController" and maybe one or two other controllers. In the current version (MVC2) we simply override the controller factory which statically checks for a valid controller. Yeah it worked but it was more a workaround which then stayed there forever. So is there any clean way for archiving this (by configuring the routes? Note that we don't use the authorize attribute. And we will be using MVC4 in the next release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add global filter and put logic into OnActionExecuting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx)

**Option 1**: Check routeValues for a correct controller and action

```
var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

**Option 2**: Check this value **Request.Url**

Actually you allow only the routes defined and nothing else, so the question is really a little odd.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that would require us to place a filter attribute on every controller, wouldn't it? We thought there may be a way to archive this by using the Registered Routes.

Comment: @JJR Register this filter globally into GlobalFilterCollection on app start (Global.asax)

Comment: We cannot use filter that way because the third party library invokes the controllers and actions and that will again trigger the global filter which will then fail. Dunno if this will be possible in any other way then overriding the controller factory :(

Comment: @JJR Try to use ASP.NET HttpModules